# Set range to a table column after autofilter, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Part of my refresh of a dashboard includes filtering an ODBC query table to show only certain projects, and then copying those project IDs to another tab in the same workbook. Because the order of projects and the results of the filtering change with each refresh of the query, I am having a hard time defining the range of project IDs to copy.

I have tried the code below, which results in the copying of only the first value in the query table copied over into every row of the display table. I've also tried referencing the range via cell references instead of table references, which resulted in the same outcome.

```
Public Sub EPC_test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("projects_master")

   'filter query table to show qualifying projects
       Set ws = wb.Sheets("projects_master")
       Dim i As Integer, lo As ListObject
        Set lo = wb.Sheets("projects_master").ListObjects(1) 'lo = query table


       i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Display Tab?", wb.Sheets("projects_master").Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)

       lo_PM.Range.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="1"

  'update range with qualifying project IDs
       Set ws_m = wb.Sheets("projects_master") 
        Set ws_BP = wb.Sheets("Display") 

    Set range1 = ws_m.Range("projects_master[ID]").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Set range2 = ws_BP.Range("Display[ID]") 

    'copy values from query to display
          range2.Value = range1.Value
```

Comment: Is "Display" the name of the sheet, the name of a `ListObject`/table on that sheet, or both?

Comment: I didn't think "Display[ID]" and "projects_master[ID]" were valid names for a named range. Are those the column headings?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon display is the name of the sheet and the list object on that sheet.

Comment: @Comintern yes, those are table headings. would it be better to reference the range via cell reference?

Comment: Rather than using `Worksheet.Range`, try going through the `ListObject` API, e.g. `Set range2 = ws_BP.ListObjects("Display").ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange`

Comment: I'd do the same for range1 too, for consistency - `Set range1 = ws_m.ListObjects("projects_master").ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: You duplicated `Set ws = wb.Sheets("projects_master")` Suggest deleting one.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for your comments -- i've tried rewriting range1 and range2 as you suggest, but am still getting the same result: only the first value in the query table is copied into the entirety of range 2